# Any more compact self-activating piston designs?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I need to push incoming blocks in a new direction using a piston activated as soon as there is a new block to be pushed. In the screenshot, if the block from below is pushed in front of the piston, it passes the signal, powers the piston, the piston pushes it away and retracts awaiting another block. That circuit satisfies my needs (for vertical->sideways transport) but is awfully "verbose" with 2x5 footprint. I'm fairly sure I saw similar circuits using one torch or something else about as compact.

[image: Piston transport]

I'm also in need similar circuits for turning the "stream of blocks" horizontally (say incoming from east, push to north) and horizontal-to-vertical (e.g. incoming from east push down or up).

Comment: I also know there are ways of turning the piston into a "bud switch" in order to achieve this, but I don't have any such designs memorized.

Comment: That would not be efficient compared to these designs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Horizontal to horizontal** (*north to east*, etc)
Use the same design, but put a redstone torch under the "hotspot" where the blocks will be pushed towards.

[image: Minecraft piston push block horizontally]

**Horizontal to downward**
Note that the input can be received from either opposing side (and you can move either the "red power line" or the "white receiver line" if you want to two "inputs" to come at 90 degree angles instead)

[image: Minecraft piston push block downward]

**Horizontal to upward**
Same as the above design, the input can be received from either opposing side (and you can move either the "red power line" or the "receiver line" (the one with the repeater) if you want to two "inputs" to come at 90 degree angles instead).

- The piston is a sticky piston.
- The repeater has to be set to 2 ticks.
- The glass block is required (but can be replaced by any transparent or non-solid, pushable block)
- The half-slabs are required (but can be of any material, or glowstone can be used instead)

[image: Minecraft piston push block upward]

Comment: You can eliminate the repeater and make it 2x2x3, just put a block is where the repeater is and place redstone on top, eliminating the 2 redstone dusts on the left. If you are making this floating, put the torch attached to the white wool instead.

Comment: @Timtech Good idea! I implemented your suggestion into the design.

Comment: Awesome job! Huge thanks, especially for the dual-sided designs!